# How to install LinqPad driver not within itself?

Tags: linqpad

Does anybody know how to install Oracle driver outside linq pad? The computer can not access internet, so have to download the driver from other computer then install it.

I downloaded the driver, but do not know how to install it. My OS is windows server 2008 R2.

Anybody can help me out will be great appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the driver [here](http://www.linqpad.net/RichClient/DataContextDrivers.aspx).

To install it, click **Add connection**, **View more drivers** then the **Browse** button.

Comment: Hi Joe, I know how to download it, but do not know how to install it. Could you please tell me how to install it after I download it? thanks.

Comment: Late for this, but may help someone: Rename the downloaded *.zip file to *.LPX, then use "view more drivers" option from "Add Connection", then Browse to the file.